# What is making this spacing?

Tags: html, css, margin, padding, spacing

I've tried setting padding/margin to 0 for the spans and divs. Also, when using the inspector, it doesn't say there is any padding/margin on any element that is causing the spacing. I have also added a picture below showing the problem I am encountering, essentially looking to get rid of the spacing between the red boxes.

[image]

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(167, 173, 240)
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(85, 86, 87);
  font-size: 50px;
}

#sum {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 190px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9.5em;
  color: pink;
  background-color: rgb(227, 86, 65);
}

.numbers {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbers span {
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  width: 16.6%;
  padding-top: 27.5px;
  height: 72.5px;
  color: pink;
  background-color: rgb(227, 86, 65);
}

div,
span {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sum">0</div>-

<div class="numbers">
  <span id="firstNum">0</span>
  <span id="secondNum">0</span>
  <span id="thirdNum">0</span>
  <span id="fourthNum">0</span>
  <span id="fifthNum">0</span>
  <span id="sixthNum">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the space between the big red box at the top and the .numbers div below it?

Comment: Did you tried removing `-` after `<div id="sum">0</div>-`?

Comment: Remove the hyphen: https://jsfiddle.net/vt6nckp4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `-` after your `#sum` DIV:

```
<div id="sum">0</div>-
```

MAke it:

```
<div id="sum">0</div>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(167, 173, 240)
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(85, 86, 87);
  font-size: 50px;
}

#sum {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 190px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9.5em;
  color: pink;
  background-color: rgb(227, 86, 65);
}

.numbers {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbers span {
  float: left;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  width: 16.6%;
  padding-top: 27.5px;
  height: 72.5px;
  color: pink;
  background-color: rgb(227, 86, 65);
}

div,
span {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="sum">0</div>

<div class="numbers">
  <span id="firstNum">0</span>
  <span id="secondNum">0</span>
  <span id="thirdNum">0</span>
  <span id="fourthNum">0</span>
  <span id="fifthNum">0</span>
  <span id="sixthNum">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Neat answer! :-)

Comment: Ah, sneaky little thing! Didn't even see that! Thank you